# Corrupted dvc.lock

Tags: dvc

I'm using DAGsHub storage as a remote and running into the following error message (when trying to DVC pull):

> ERROR: Lockfile 'bias_tagging_model/dvc.lock' is corrupted.

I thought I might have messed something up, but when cloning the git repo again and DVC pulling I am still running into this.
The data looks ok when viewed in the browser.
If you have any ideas, I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Hey, could you please run it with `-v` and share a bit more details? Also, would be great to see the `dvc version` output. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, the reason for this error is the DVC version.

If the dvc.lock file has a DVC 2.* schema and you are using a lower version, it will throw this error.

Upgrade your DVC version, and it should work.